# Dart Higher-Order function with Generics

Tags: dart, future

I'm trying to create a simple **debug/print** function that I can pipe through a sequence of **then** while processing Future results in Dart.

My function definition is as follows:

```
import 'dart:async';

typedef FutureOr<T> Pipe<T>(T pipeThrough);
Pipe<A> debug<A>(String log) {
  return (A pipeThrough) {
    print(log);
    return pipeThrough;
  };
}
```

It will return a function that just pipes through whatever it has received from the Future chain, and before that it will print the message **log** that has been sent to **debug**.

The way I'm using the function is quite simple:

```
Future<Map> load(String folder) {
  return File(Paths.of([folder, 'data.json']))
      .readAsString()
      .then((s) => jsonDecode(s))
      .then(debug<Map>('JSON LOADED!'));
}
```

As you can see in the last **then** in the future chain, it is supposed to return whatever was in the chain, but before that print **'JSON LOADED!'**.

But there is something with the generics and Future api that I didn't manage to find a way to make it work, here's the error:

```
Unhandled exception:
type '(Map<dynamic, dynamic>) => Map<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => FutureOr<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'
#0      load (file:///{.../..../......}/data/data_json.dart:11:13)
#1      main (file:///{.../..../......}/data/main.dart:7:28)
#2      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:301:19)
#3      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

I've tried a bunch of different things, but fundamentally I don't get what's happening, doesn't dart infer the proper types based on the generic types annotation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know *why* it can't handle the type here, but changing the code to

```
Future<Map> load(String folder) {
  return File(Paths.of([folder, 'data.json']))
      .readAsString()
      .then((s) => jsonDecode(s))
      .then((v) => debug<Map>('JSON LOADED!')(v));
}
```

fixes your issue. I had thought that this should be equivalent...